# How to extract data the ip address from this format

Tags: pandas

The rows in column A are always have the following format:

```
dns_name (dns-server) Ip_addr_of_the_server, datacenter_location.
```

An example would be:

```
linux_test (dns-1-intern) 10.10.10.250, Berlin_DC.
```

What argument i should add to `split()` function to get only the ip address?

The result should be: `10.10.10.250` (just the ip add, that's all)

Comment: `df.A.str.split().str[2].str[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1:

Using regex with `str.extract` to extract the string between the `)` and `,` in your column:

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['linux_test (dns-1-intern) 10.10.10.250, Berlin_DC']})

df['IP'] = df['A'].str.extract('(?<=\))(.*?)(?=\,)')
```

---

```
                                                   A             IP
0  linux_test (dns-1-intern) 10.10.10.250, Berlin_DC   10.10.10.250
```

---

#### Method 2:

Using only `pandas` with `str.find` and string slicing:

```
paranthesis = df['A'].str.find(')').values[0]
comma = df['A'].str.find(',').values[0]

df['IP'] = df['A'].str[paranthesis+2:comma]
```

---

```
                                                   A             IP
0  linux_test (dns-1-intern) 10.10.10.250, Berlin_DC   10.10.10.250
```

#### Method 3

Using regex again, but this time find the pattern of your IP address

**Note**, this is not very general, since your IP address can differ

```
df['A'].str.extract('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')

              0
0  10.10.10.250
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple IP within one string , using `findall`

```
df['IP']=df['A'].str.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})').str[0]
df
Out[246]: 
                                                   A            IP
0  linux_test (dns-1-intern) 10.10.10.250, Berlin_DC  10.10.10.250
```